# How to set default color back when using vscode decorator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension that calls `let regEx = new RegExp(somePattern)` and then does the following

```
   while ((match = regEx.exec(text))) { 
      // This loop runs till there is no more match left in the entire text 
      // When match found It colored the selected text to red
   }
```

The above method calls whenever some activity happens in the active editor. Problem is, the first time when the pattern matches it changes the text color to red, works expectedly.

But now, If I make changes to the original text so that regex doesn't match anymore, I want to set the color back to its default.

How will I handle this situation? Is there any approach built-in with vscode decorator to handle my situation?

One possible solution: If I run another regex that will return all the text that does not match the regex and then I can apply default color on them. But is this approach feasible? I think this is not a performance-friendly solution. Any help, suggestion, hints are welcome.

**Explanation & EXPECTATION:**

// Email: abc@test.com

In the text editor whenever someone types like the above sentence the regex will detect ***// Email:*** and hence it will change the background color of the text to red.

Now later, if someone makes any changes, for example:
*// Something: abc@test.com*

**I want to revert back to its default color since its no longer matches the regex.**

Currently, even after removing/changing  **// Email:** to something different text still shows the color that I set earlier.

**Actual Code:**

```
while ((match = regEx.exec(text))) {
            const startPos = activeEditor.document.positionAt(match.index);
            const endPos = activeEditor.document.positionAt(match.index + match[0].length);

            /* Ranges */
            let singleRange: vscode.Range = new vscode.Range(startPos, endPos);
            ranges.push(singleRange);
        }
        activeEditor.setDecorations(fontColorDecorator, ranges);
```

[image]

Comment: According to me; you can call the method every time the edit is made to the document or to that particular text(if it seems)

Comment: This method is invoked from both onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(), onDidChangeTextDocument().

Comment: show the code you use to `color the text red`

Comment: don't recreate the decorator each time there is an edit, use the same decorator for each call to `setDecorations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a decoration type with

```
myDecoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType(options);
```

do this **outside** the `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor()` callback function.

In the `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor()` callback
you calculate the ranges that should need to be decorated and add them to the editor

```
editor.setDecorations(myDecoration, arOfRanges);
```

From the docs `setDecorations()`

> Adds a set of decorations to the text editor. If a set of decorations already exists with the given decoration type, they will be replaced.

Next time you calculate the ranges affected you might get an empty array and the decorations are removed or updated.

```
editor.setDecorations(myDecoration, []);
```

Comment: I have updated the questions with a code snippet and an image. Please check.

Comment: @ShahriarHossain I have modified the answer a bit

Comment: Thanks. Declaring the decorator outside of onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(), onDidChangeTextDocument() solved my issue.